# Cannot use ++, -- operator on the result from pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm using VS Code and GCC compiler.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main()
{
    void *ptr = malloc(100);    

    printf("%p\n", ptr);               
    printf("%p\n", (int *)ptr + 1);    
    printf("%p\n", (int *)ptr - 1);    

    void *ptr2 = ptr; 

    printf("%p\n", (int *)ptr2 + 1);  // Works well

    printf("%p\n", ++(int *)ptr2);    // error: lvalue required as decrement operand



    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code above, `++(int *)ptr2` gets the error: "lvalue required as decrement operand".

However, `(int *)ptr2 + 1` does work.
Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of a cast is not an lvalue. There's a footnote in the `6.5.4 Cast operators` section of ISO C11 which states that:

> A cast does not yield an lvalue. Thus, a cast to a qualified type has the same effect as a cast to the unqualified version of the type.

Similarly, in `6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators`, it states (my emphasis):

> The operand of the prefix increment or decrement operator shall have atomic, qualified,
>   or unqualified real or pointer type, ***and shall be a modifiable lvalue.***

Hence what you're attempting to do is invalid.

The reason why `(int *)ptr2 + 1` works is because `ptr2` *is* an lvalue so it can be cast. The addition of `1` is done to the cast value and this is also valid.

The situation you are attempting is no different to something like `++(ptr+1)`, which is a *different* way of trying to increment a non-lvalue. It's because both your cast and the expression `ptr+1` are *ephemeral* objects, required to exist only long enough to be used for the immediate operation (the addition or the cast, *not* the pre-increment).

Your problem goes away if you slightly re-engineer the way things are done (since `void*` casts freely to and from most other pointers):

```
printf("%p\n", ptr2 = ((int*)ptr2) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `++` operator requires an lvalue as operand, and its side-effect is to update the value stored in the memory location designated by the value.

The result of a cast is not an lvalue, there is no associated memory location where the `int *` value is stored.  You might call it a temporary value. So `++` cannot be applied to it .